# Fatal error: Class 'google_sitemap' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, sitemap

I use google codeigniter and i want use sitemap but get following error, how can fix it?

I get this class from here: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Google_Sitemaps

Error:

> Fatal error: Class 'google_sitemap' not found in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\sitemap_google.php on line 13

This is full code in Controller in here: D:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\sitemap_google.php:

```
<?php
class Sitemap_google extends CI_Controller
{
    function My_controller()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->helper(array('text','url'));
        $this->load->plugin('google_sitemap'); //Load Plugin
    }

    function index()
    {
        $sitemap = new google_sitemap; //This is line 13
        $item = new google_sitemap_item(base_url()."MY_WEBSITE_URL",date("Y-m-d"), 'weekly', '0.8' ); //Create a new Item
        $sitemap->add_item($item); //Append the item to the sitemap object
        $sitemap->build("./sitemap.xml"); //Build it...

         //Let's compress it to gz
        $data = implode("", file("./sitemap.xml"));
        $gzdata = gzencode($data, 9);
        $fp = fopen("./sitemap.xml.gz", "w");
        fwrite($fp, $gzdata);
        fclose($fp);

        //Let's Ping google
        $this->_pingGoogleSitemaps(base_url()."/sitemap.xml.gz");
    }

    function _pingGoogleSitemaps( $url_xml )
    {
       $status = 0;
       $google = 'www.google.com';
       if( $fp=@fsockopen($google, 80) )
       {
          $req =  'GET /webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=' .
                  urlencode( $url_xml ) . " HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
                  "Host: $google\r\n" .
                  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; " .
                  PHP_OS . ") PHP/" . PHP_VERSION . "\r\n" .
                  "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
          fwrite( $fp, $req );
          while( !feof($fp) )
          {
             if( @preg_match('~^HTTP/\d\.\d (\d+)~i', fgets($fp, 128), $m) )
             {
                $status = intval( $m[1] );
                break;
             }
          }
          fclose( $fp );
       }
       return( $status );
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter are you using? You can check with `echo CI_VERSION`. I ask because "plugins" have been removed for a while now.

Comment: I use last version of Codeigniter.

Comment: If `My_controller` is supposed to be the constructor, you're doing it wrong. I think you've mixed up the library and your normal controller. Call `__construct()` instead of `MY_Controller()`.

Comment: @jenniferJolie: What does `echo CI_VERSION` say? You said you're on the latest version: which version number would that be?

Comment: Yes, i use of version 2.1.0. I try it, getting error, see my url: http://www.neginph.com/sitemap_google/

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->plugin('google_sitemap'); //Load Plugin
```

You said:

> I use last version of Codeigniter.

There are no more "plugins" in Codeigniter.

It looks like you're expecting at least two classes in one file: `google_sitemap_item` and `google_sitemap`. CI's loader doesn't play well with that (it expects one class per file), so don't even bother with the CI loader, just do a straight include:

```
include APPPATH.'path/to/file/google_sitemap.php');
```

You're also using the old PHP4 constructors, which suggests you're using an older version of CI (current is 2.1.0, you can check with `echo CI_VERSION;`). So, this:

```
function My_controller()
{
    parent::Controller();
    $this->load->helper(array('text','url'));
    $this->load->plugin('google_sitemap'); //Load Plugin
}
```

Should be this:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('text','url'));
    include APPPATH.'path/to/file/google_sitemap.php');
}
```

Comment: Your path to `./sitemap.xml` is incorrect. Remember that CI is always running on `index.php`, so all paths should be relative from there. Either the file doesn't exist in your root directory or you've provided the wrong path. Failing that, try an absolute path, like `FCPATH.'sitemap.xml'` At the very least, your class file is now loading properly.